# pass custom scaling operation in python

Tags: python, function, lambda, mean

i am following an example of the https://github.com/google/lightweight_mmm but instead of using the default setting for scalars, which is mean:

```
media_scaler = preprocessing.CustomScaler(divide_operation=jnp.mean)
```

i need to use the lambda function:

```
lambda x: jnp.mean(x[x > 0])
```

How can this be done? I tried couple of things, but since i am a complete beginner, i feel lost.

So i have tried:

```
lambda x: jnp.mean(x[x > 0])
media_scaler = preprocessing.CustomScaler(divide_operation=x)
```

and

```
lambda x: jnp.mean(x[x > 0])
media_scaler = preprocessing.CustomScaler(divide_operation=lambda)
```

None of these work.

Comment: can you show us the things you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```py
div = lambda x: jnp.mean(x[x > 0])
media_scaler = preprocessing.CustomScaler(divide_operation=div)
```

Comment: unfortunatelly this doesnt work with an error "NameError: name 'x' is not defined"

Comment: You're just throwing away the `lambda`.  The `x` is a parameter it takes, *not* a name that it gets assigned to.

Comment: @Nneka my mistake, have fixed this now. jasonharper, thanks for pointing out

Comment: i have tried the proposed solution (see my question), that also doesn't work

Comment: i am sorry, the solution works! It fails in the step after, i will open a new question for that